# "parse error at end of input", but I'm sure my brackets are correct. (in C)

Tags: c, parsing, curly-brackets

I'm pretty sure my brackets are matched up correctly, but I'm getting the error "parse error at end of input" No matter how many or few brackets I attach to the end of this program. Since all of the Google results for this error say that the fix lies in the brackets, I'm at a loss for what else it could be. Could someone point out my silly little mistake for me? :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/user/cse320/Projects/project06.support.h"
#include "/user/cse320/Projects/project06.hardware.h"

void execute()
{
  unsigned long int IRdecode;
  IRdecode = IR;
  IRdecode >> 30;

  if ( IRdecode == 0 )
  {

    unsigned int _reg = IR;
    unsigned int _imm = IR;

    _reg << 2;
    _reg >> 27;

    _imm << 9;

    write_reg_file( _reg, _imm );
  }

  if ( IRdecode == 00000002 )
  {

    unsigned int _op3 = IR;
    unsigned int _rd = IR;
    unsigned int _rs1 = IR;
    _op3 << 7;
    _op3 >> 26;

    _rd << 2;  
    _rd >> 30;

    _rs1 << 13;
    _rs1 >> 27;

    if ( _op3 == 00000001 ){
      //AND }
    if ( _op3 == 00000002 ){
      //OR } 
    if ( _op3 == 00000003 ){
      //XOR } 
    if ( _op3 == 00000005 ){
      //ANDN }
    if ( _op3 == 00000006 ){
      //ORN } 
    if ( _op3 == 00000007 ){
      //XNOR }
  } 
}
```

Comment: If you look at the syntax highlighting SO gave it, you should see the problem.

Comment: Oh gosh, you're totally right. I didn't even think about the comment lines eating my brackets. Lol, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using  `//AND }` for comment which will comment every thing in same line, results `}` to be commented.

**CODE:**

```
if ( _op3 == 00000001 ){
  //AND }                //here } will be commented.
```

You should use like this

```
 if ( _op3 == 00000001 ){
  //AND 
 }                          //now OK
```

**OR**

```
 if ( _op3 == 00000001 ){
  /*AND*/  }               //OK, as well
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is something strange going on, I think there is also another problem with your code (other than the problem with the comments):

```
_op3 << 7;
_op3 >> 26;

_rd << 2;  
_rd >> 30;

_rs1 << 13;
_rs1 >> 27;
```

These bitshift operations are completely useless because the result is discarded. The `<<` operator is just like the `+` operator in the way that it takes two operands and produces a result. What would you expect the following to do?

```
i + 4;
2 + 4;
1 + 9;
```

I think what you want is the compound operators:

```
_op3 <<= 7;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
_op3 = op3 << 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the closing braces of the `if` statements are accidentally commented out:

```
if ( _op3 == 00000001 ){
  //AND }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your only problem (since you say adding lots of braces at the end of the program does not help) but in the statements like this ...

```
if ( _op3 == 00000001 ){
  //AND }
```

`//` comments run to the end of the line, therefore you have *commented out the close brace*.  Try using `/*AND*/` and so forth, instead.

If that doesn't cure the problem, please post *preprocessed* source code, which you can get with `gcc -E`.  Warning: this will produce a very large file, which you should cut down to the smallest thing you can manage that still causes the problem.